# Firebase Security Rules to allow read

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am learning about Firebase Database and am trying to set up security rules. To start, I am creating very permissive rules with something like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/users/{user_id} {
    allow read, write: if true;
  }
}
```

I found the Rules Playground tool in the Firebase Console and attempt to `get` a document:

[image]

But when I click Run, I get "Simulated read denied".

What am I missing? Why doesn't my rule allow the read? What do I need to change to allow reads and writes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules are just incorrect.  It look like you edited down the path too far.  Your outer match should always be "/databases/{database}/documents".  The whole thing should look like this if you want to allow full access to the users collection:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user_id} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I'm confused how most of the examples at https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language even work then. Many of them don't have nested `match` blocks.

Comment: Don't look at the ones for service "firebase.storage".  Use only "cloud.firestore".

Comment: ahh...I didn't even notice that difference.